# Have different entries in startmenu dependent on what user has chosen to install

Tags: windows, installation, nsis

I'm making use of optional installation of components in NSIS installer as shown in [Controlling Available Install Options](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Controlling_Available_Install_Options) on the NSIS wiki.

This works fine, dependent on what options the user has chosen, the related parts are installed.

But now there is a problem with the start menu entries which come in a separate section:

```
Section -startmenu
SetShellVarContext all
CreateDirectory "$SMPROGRAMS\MyInstall"
CreateShortCut "$SMPROGRAMS\MyInstallOpenAPC\Editor1.lnk" "$INSTDIR\Editor1.exe" "" "$INSTDIR\icon.ico" 0
CreateShortCut "$SMPROGRAMS\MyInstallOpenAPC\Editor2.lnk" "$INSTDIR\Editor2.exe" "" "$INSTDIR\icon.ico" 0
CreateShortCut "$SMPROGRAMS\MyInstallOpenAPC\Editor3.lnk" "$INSTDIR\Editor3.exe" "" "$INSTDIR\icon.ico" 0
CreateShortCut "$SMPROGRAMS\MyInstallOpenAPC\Editor4.lnk" "$INSTDIR\Editor4.exe" "" "$INSTDIR\icon.ico" 0
Sectionend
```

Dependent on the optionally installed packages I want to create only some of the start menu entries.

How can this be done? How can I create a relation between start menu entries and the installed sections?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if the relevant component (section) is selected:

```
!include LogicLib.nsh
InstallDir "$ProgramFiles\MyApp"
Page Components
Page InstFiles

Section "Foo" SID_FOO
SetOutPath "$InstDir\Foo"
; ...
SectionEnd

Section "Bar" SID_BAR
SetOutPath "$InstDir\Bar"
; ...
SectionEnd

Section "Start menu shortcuts"
SetShellVarContext all
${If} ${SectionIsSelected} ${SID_FOO}
    CreateDirectory "$SMPROGRAMS\MyApp"
    CreateShortcut "$SMPROGRAMS\MyApp\Foo.lnk" "$InstDir\Foo\Foo.exe"
${EndIf}
${If} ${SectionIsSelected} ${SID_BAR}
    CreateDirectory "$SMPROGRAMS\MyApp"
    CreateShortcut "$SMPROGRAMS\MyApp\Bar.lnk" "$InstDir\Bar\Bar.exe"
${EndIf}
SectionEnd
```